# How to get the array index of an @name from an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, database

I have a textarea and a dropdown set. I have it set so if a user does `@name` (or anything) it will display a dropdown list of users with specified input. I don't know how to do the regex for searching an array for an `@name` within it.

Example: User types `"Hi @bob"`, then array is `["Hi","@bob"]`;

How do I find where `@bob` is and if a user hit spaces afterwords, the regex detects if a space is placed right after it.

example code I have tried

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

 if(keycode == 64) { //Enter keycode
 $('.postingArea').on("keyup", function(){

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var res = inputVal.split(" ");
    console.log(jQuery.inArray( "@/w/", res ));

var myString = inputVal.match(/@([^ ]*)/)[1]; 
 var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result2");


if (jQuery.inArray( "@", res ) < 1) {
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }else {

        $.get("../Admin/Users/SearchUser.php", {userAtd: myString}).done(function(data){
            // Display the returned data in browser
            resultDropdown.html(data);

        });
    } 
 })
}
```

This sort of works, but `jQuery.inArray` doesn't accept regex, so it only works when @ is clicked, but not for the rest of the letters following. And then it should detect when there is a space after the word so then it knows that the @ is done.

When doing console.log(res); The output in log is ["this", "is", "a", "test", "@user"]
What I need is for it to detect when @ is clicked and then when that part of the array is finished such as hitting space since hitting space makes the array res now 
["this", "is", "a", "test", "@user",""]

Comment: Could you post an example of what "res" looks like when you get a result ? This would help us to understand expected result.

Comment: res? it just splits the input value string into an array. Example: console.log(res) = 
["this", "is", "a", "test", "@user"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, @Flo's response helped a bit coming up with this. I had to detect two different array lengths and compare the two and find where the @ started between both arrays and then set a variable x to the length of the original input and then do a .test as my if statement. Code down below

```
// @'d feature
$(document).keypress(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

 if(keycode == 64) { //Enter keycode
 $('.postingArea').on("keyup", function(){

    var inputVal = $('.postingArea').val();
    var res = inputVal.split(" ");

 var res2 = inputVal.match(/@[a-z\d]+/ig);

 var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result2");
var x=0;
if(x <= res2.length){
   x = res.length-1;
}

if(/@[a-z\d]+/ig.test(res[x])) {
  var myString = res[x]; 

        $.get("../Admin/Users/SearchUser.php", {userAtd: myString}).done(function(data){
            // Display the returned data in browser
            resultDropdown.html(data);

        });


    }else {



          resultDropdown.empty();

    } 
  })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex to extract every words that start by "@" and that have space after it in a string.

`/@[a-z\d]+/ig`

See examples : https://regex101.com/r/WDZNyl/1

Once  you get the list, it will be easier for you to find the desired values in database.

Comment: where would I put this? jQuery.inArray doesn't accept regex unfortunately

Comment: Instead of doing ```var res = inputVal.split(" ");``` to get the string as a list. You could just make ```var res = inputVal.match(/@[a-z\d]+/ig)```. You then would have either an empty list if nothing matched, or a list of @words that are in your sentence... You then would not need to check if "@" exists in array as the length of the array tells you if an "@" has been found.

Comment: so when I do this, how do i set my if function then, because the if function is suppose to be like if the @name has a space after it, then it'll do the dropdown.empty(); else, it'll continue looking for that username